# Sinatra: access to optional parameter

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In code like this,

```
get '/posts.?:format?' do
  # ...
end
```

How can I get the format that was requested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the `params` hash as in a no-optional param situation:

```
params[:format]
```